# increase pagination limit wordpress

Tags: wordpress

This is how i am iterating all the wordpress post under certain category. it is giving me only 10 posts per category.

```
<ul>
   <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <li>
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
      <?php the_Title(); ?>
      </a>
   </li>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
   </div>
</ul>
<?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>
```

How can i increase this limit ?

This is what i tried so far.

```
<?php while ( have_posts(array('posts_per_page' => '20')) ) : the_post(); ?>
```

it is not working as expected. any help ?

Answer (score 0):

change per page limit

go to wp-admin then

```
wp-admin -> Settings -> Reading -> Blog pages show at most (defult is 10. you can change your pagination per page limit here.) -> Save Changes
```

or

```
<?php
$post_type = 'post'; //your post type name here
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$post_args=array(
    'type'                     => $post_type,
    'post_status'              => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'           => 20,
    'paged'                    => $paged, 
    'caller_get_posts'         => -1,
    'child_of'                 => 0,
    'parent'                   => 0,
    'orderby'                  => 'name', 
    'order'                    => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'               => 0,
    'hierarchical'             => 1,
    'exclude'                  => '',
    'include'                  => '',
    'number'                   => '',
    'pad_counts'               => false, 
);
$post_my_query = null;
$post_my_query = new WP_Query($post_args);

if( $post_my_query->have_posts() ) :
?>
    <ul>
        <?php
            while ($post_my_query->have_posts()) : $post_my_query->the_post(); 
            ?>
            <li>
              <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
              <?php the_Title(); ?>
              </a>
           </li>
            <?php
           endwhile;
       ?>
    </ul>
<?php
else :      
    echo '<p>No Post Found!</p>';   
endif;
wp_reset_query($post_my_query);
the_posts_navigation(); 
?>
```